# JBoss multiple SLF4J bindings error, how do I cause multiple log implementation to co-exist

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, slf4j

I'm running JBoss 4.2GA on Java 8 runtime.

I have an ear which has multiple wars that have conflicting SLF4J bindings,

`/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar and log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.2.jar.`

Can I cause them to co-exist and not "complain" about each other?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there ARE multiple bindings, so the complaining is completely valid. It's just an information, though, SLF4J will decide which binding to use and stick with it. If you don't want the message, you'll have to exclude the dependency you don't want in your .war files. As in the end, only one binding will be used anyway, it's a good idea to make that choice yourself instead of letting some code pick one randomly.

The [documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings) says this:

> The warning emitted by SLF4J is just that, a warning. Even when
>   multiple bindings are present, SLF4J will pick one logging
>   framework/implementation and bind with it. The way SLF4J picks a
>   binding is determined by the JVM and for all practical purposes should
>   be considered random. As of version 1.6.6, SLF4J will name the
>   framework/implementation class it is actually bound to.

and...

> Embedded components such as libraries or frameworks should not declare
>   a dependency on any SLF4J binding but only depend on slf4j-api. When a
>   library declares a compile-time dependency on a SLF4J binding, it
>   imposes that binding on the end-user, thus negating SLF4J's purpose.